# Showing error message in terminal

Tags: python

When I am opening a terminal it is always showing the below error message.

```
WARNING:root:python-html2text is not present. HTML pages will not be converted into text.
```

Please help me how can I remove this error.

I have tried many times to install `python-html2text` from Ubuntu software center as well as using command from terminal but it is not happening.

It is showing the message `Requires installation of untrusted packages` and `This requires installing packages from unauthenticated sources.`

Please help me a way out.

Answer (score 3):

Try this.  just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install html2text
sudo apt-get install python-html2text
```